# General Structuring of Recursive Induction

Tags: induction, recursion

I'm currently learning recursive induction, but I'm really struggling on how to do recursive induction questions.

I'm fine with normal induction (i.e. prove that $1+2+3+...+n=\frac{n(n+1)}2$, and prove that $6^n+4$ is divisible by 5 for all positive integer $n$) and I know how to set it out

> 1. Prove true for $n=1$
> 2. Assume true for $n=k$
> 3. Prove true for $n=k+1$

My understanding for working out recursive induction is that you have to assume that $n=k$, as well as $n=k+1$, are true or something.

Is there a set out way of doing recursive induction, and/or is there a textbook that has a really good explanation on how to do recursive induction?

Here's a question that I have to do

> A sequence is defined recursively as $u_1=3$, $u_2=33$ and $u_n=11u_{n-1}-28u_{n-2}$ for $n≥3$. Prove that $u_n=7^n-4^n$ for all positive integers $n$.

Appreciate the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doing recursive induction is not really any different in general from induction in other situations. However, for your particular question, you should use [strong induction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_induction#Complete_(strong)_induction) to prove your stated result since it involves using $2$ previous values. First, I assume the recursive statement is

$$u_n=11u_{n-1}-28u_{n-2}, \; n \ge 3 \tag{1}\label{eq1A}$$

where your stated second term being $-28u_{n-1}$ is a typo. The statement you're asking to prove is

$$u_n=7^n-4^n, \; n \ge 1 \tag{2}\label{eq2A}$$

You first check your $2$ base cases. You have $u_1 = 3$, with \eqref{eq2A} giving $u_1 = 7 - 3$, so it matches. Similarly, \eqref{eq2A} gives $u_2 = 7^2 - 4^2 = 49 - 16 = 33$, which matches the given base case of $u_2 = 33$.

Next, assume that for some integer $k \ge 2$, \eqref{eq2A} holds for all positive integers $n \le k$ (this is the *strong* induction part). Using this assumption, then for $n = k + 1$, \eqref{eq1A} gives

$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
u_{k+1} & = 11u_k - 28u_{k-1} \\
& = 11(7^k - 4^k) - 28(7^{k-1} - 4^{k-1}) \\
& = 11(7^k) - 11(4^k) - \left((4)(7)\right)(7^{k-1}) + \left((7)(4)\right)(4^{k-1}) \\
& = 11(7^k) - 11(4^k) - 4(7^{k}) + 7(4^{k}) \\
& = 7(7^k) - 4(4^k) \\
& = 7^{k+1} - 4^{k+1}
\end{aligned}\end{equation}\tag{3}\label{eq3A}$$

This matches what is expected from \eqref{eq2A}, showing that it also holds for $n = k + 1$. Thus, by strong induction, \eqref{eq2A} is true for all $n \ge 1$.

FYI, you could also more directly find and prove \eqref{eq2A} by determining & using the characteristics roots of \eqref{eq1A} such as explained in [Linear difference equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_difference_equation).